# What is the difference between SQL and SOQL?

Tags: c#, sql, soql

Can any one explain the difference between `SQL`(Structured Query Language) and `SOQL`(Salesforce Object Query Language)?

I need to convert dynamic `SQL` query into `SOQL` query using `C#`.
Did anyone have any idea please help me...

Sample Inner Join Query:

```
SELECT "Salesforce"."Account"."Id", "Salesforce"."Account"."Name",
 "Salesforce"."Account"."Type", "Salesforce"."Contact"."FirstName",
 "Salesforce"."Contact"."LastName" 
FROM ( "Salesforce"."Contact" INNER JOIN 
"Salesforce"."Account" ON
 "Salesforce"."Contact"."AccountId" = "Salesforce"."Account"."Id")
```

Comment: [Related question on SalesForce site](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000guwAAAQ)

Comment: @john I already saw few sites.but i need to convert dynamic SQL query into SOQL query using C#.you have a idea ....

Comment: What do you mean by 'using C#'. Are you writing a SQL - SOQL converter for it in C#? Do you expect someone to just built that and post it here? Or do you just want to run SOQL in C# that does what you posted?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I need to just convert SQL query into SOQL query and it into c#.

Comment: So you want to run a SOQL query from C#? I lookaed at this guide and the simple SOQL looks identical. Did you try it and see? https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET

Comment: @Nick I have only SQL query ,I need to change SQL query into SOQL Query and Run that SOQL query from C#.....

Comment: `I need to convert dynamic SQL query into SOQL query using C#.` Why do you need to do this? This sounds like a XY Problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The first practical attempt should be to just run the SQL you have, get an error message and find out how to solve that error message

Answer (score 3):

Some difference of SOQL:

- No SELECT *
- No views
- SOQL read-only
- Limited indexes
- Object-relational mapping is automatic
- Schema changes protected

Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/From_SQL_to_SOQL

Comment: Thanks.But I need to convert SQL query to SOQL query using C#.you have a idea ...

Answer (score 3):

I searched for three minutes while my son was distracting me and found this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm

Which indicates this is valid syntax for selecting data from account and contact:

```
SELECT Account.Name, (
    SELECT Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName 
    FROM Account.Contacts) 
FROM Account
```

You should start here and use similar constructs to add any other required info.

Again..... *try something.. anything* then you'll get an error message that you can research... or post on this site

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending your valuable time with me.Thanks once an for your suggestion bro..

Comment: Three minutes isn't much time and I learnt something which is great. The important question is: if you are the person who has to complete this task, how is it that you have not managed to find this yet? It's not that far into the documentation, which is the _first_ place you should have looked? Did you even look there?